# MySQL - Doing addition from "subquery field" in SELECT using alias

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to add some SUMs from subqueries in the SELECT into another new field. Here is the query that I am currently using:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(date) AS day, DATE_FORMAT(date, "%d-%m-%Y") AS date,
    (SELECT SUM(qty) AS product1_shift1
    FROM bill_details 
        JOIN bills ON bills.bill_id=bill_details.bill_id
    WHERE bills.shift_id='48c73e3d-57de-4fea-aae4-7222d7e6afed'
    AND bills.date=bills_master.date) AS product1_shift1,
    (SELECT SUM(qty) AS product1_shift2
    FROM bill_details 
        JOIN bills ON bills.bill_id=bill_details.bill_id
    WHERE bills.shift_id='463ec995-cfad-46ff-8e65-3115e6e651c5'
    AND bills.date=bills_master.date) AS product1_shift2,
    (SELECT SUM(qty) AS product1_shift3
    FROM bill_details 
        JOIN bills ON bills.bill_id=bill_details.bill_id
    WHERE bills.shift_id='0a792c5f-84a6-4534-818c-427cfe8cd3ca'
    AND bills.date=bills_master.date) AS product1_shift3
FROM bills bills_master
GROUP BY bills_master.date
```

And here is the output:
[image: query output]

Notice that the product1_shift1 field is a subquery result. I would like to do the product1_shift1+product1_shift2+prdduct1_shift3. I keep getting the

> Unknown column 'product1_shift1' in 'field list'

error when I tried to add another SELECT field like

`product1_shift1+product1_shift2+product1_shift3`.

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: You can't reference the _column_ product1_shift1 in the same SELECT list as it is defined.

Comment: Try putting your existing SQL in a CTE and then selecting from it in your main SQL statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your sql query in a CTE then calculate your total as follows :

```
with cte as (
  SELECT DAYNAME(date) AS day, DATE_FORMAT(date, "%d-%m-%Y") AS date,
    (
      SELECT SUM(qty) as sum_qty
      FROM bill_details 
      JOIN bills ON bills.bill_id=bill_details.bill_id
      WHERE bills.shift_id='48c73e3d-57de-4fea-aae4-7222d7e6afed'
      AND bills.date=bills_master.date
    ) AS product1_shift1,
    (
      SELECT SUM(qty) as sum_qty
      FROM bill_details 
      JOIN bills ON bills.bill_id=bill_details.bill_id
      WHERE bills.shift_id='463ec995-cfad-46ff-8e65-3115e6e651c5'
      AND bills.date=bills_master.date
    ) AS product1_shift2,
    (
       SELECT SUM(qty) as sum_qty
       FROM bill_details 
       JOIN bills ON bills.bill_id=bill_details.bill_id
       WHERE bills.shift_id='0a792c5f-84a6-4534-818c-427cfe8cd3ca'
       AND bills.date=bills_master.date
    ) AS product1_shift3
  FROM bills bills_master
  GROUP BY bills_master.date
)
select *, COALESCE(product1_shift1,0) + COALESCE(product1_shift2,0) + COALESCE(product1_shift3,0) as total
from cte
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it helps me with the COASLESCE.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the subqueries.
Use a `LEFT` join of `bills` to `bill_details` and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(b.date) AS day, 
       DATE_FORMAT(b.date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.shift_id = '48c73e3d-57de-4fea-aae4-7222d7e6afed' THEN bd.qty END) AS product1_shift1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.shift_id = '463ec995-cfad-46ff-8e65-3115e6e651c5' THEN bd.qty END) AS product1_shift2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.shift_id = '0a792c5f-84a6-4534-818c-427cfe8cd3ca' THEN bd.qty END) AS product1_shift3,
       SUM(bd.qty) AS product1_shift_total
FROM bills b LEFT JOIN bill_details bd
ON bd.bill_id = b.bill_id
AND b.shift_id IN ('48c73e3d-57de-4fea-aae4-7222d7e6afed', '463ec995-cfad-46ff-8e65-3115e6e651c5', '0a792c5f-84a6-4534-818c-427cfe8cd3ca')
GROUP BY b.date;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, it helps me to write a shorter code

Comment: @DenjanD I'm curious why you don't prefer shorter and scalable code.

Comment: I was in a hurry so I write what I can thought about in a short time

Comment: @DenjanD when you find some time maybe you can explain why you prefer many subqueries instead of a single aggregation query.